# How to access Mass Effect 2 DLC?

Tags: mass-effect-2

I bought Mass Effect 2 with some additional DLC content on Steam and setup an account on the Cerberus network.

I have completed the campaign, however I do not notice any of the bonus missions and extras the DLC offered?

I should be able to do the Shadow Broker mission, The Thief, and some other extras.

How do I access them? Have I missed something? I have been looking on Google and some people are saying the DLC is only unlocked if you start a new campaign after completing Mass Effect 2.

Any ideas how to access the content?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To install your DLCs, you have to go onto the bioware page and download the installers.  Log in and [download them here](http://social.bioware.com/page/me2-dlc).  Steam doesn't handle any ME2 DLC and this is one of the reasons why there have been issues between EA games and Steam.

Comment: Actually the page you linked is the purchase page, the download URL is http://social.bioware.com/user_entitlements.php (once you're logged in). If you haven't already redeemed the DLC codes (ones purchased through Steam should be offered through a Steam popup as you start the game) you can redeem them here http://social.bioware.com/redeem_code.php

Comment: All the links in this answer and comment are dead.

Answer (score 2):

Download all the DLC installers from here:

https://help.ea.com/en-ca/help/origin/origin/download-dlc-for-classic-origin-games/#masseffect

You have to run each one (they are installer exe files).

If you have issues activating them see this question:
["Communication with the Mass Effect 2 server was interrupted or has timed out" error?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/327552/communication-with-the-mass-effect-2-server-was-interrupted-or-has-timed-out-e)